# Laravel - MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php

Tags: php, laravel, post, routes, laravel-5

I'm working with Laravel 5.2 and get this message:

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php at line 219:
at RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('GET', 'HEAD')) in RouteCollection.php line 206
```

I'm trying to update a user, this is my route list:
[image]

This is how my routes and controller looks like:

**Routes:**

```
Route::get('user/profile/{userid}', 'UserController@show');
Route::get('user/edit/{id}', 'UserController@edit');
Route::post('user/edit/{id}', 'UserController@store');
```

**UserController:**

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $user = User::findOrFail($id);

    $this->validate($request, [
        'voornaam' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:klanten',
        'achternaam' => 'required|max:255',
        'geboortedatum' => 'required|max:10',
        'niveau' => 'required|max:255',
        'adres' => 'required|max:255',
        'postcode' => 'required|max:6',
        'woonplaats' => 'required|max:255',
        'telefoonnummer' => 'required|max:10'
    ]);

    $input = $request->all();
    $user->fill($input)->save();

    Session::flash('flash_message', 'Gebruiker succesvol gewijzigd!!');

    return redirect()->back();
}

public function edit($id)
{
    $user = User::findOrFail($id);
    return view('user.edit', ['user' => $user]);
}
```

I don't use the html form builder but i read that if you don't use a form builder you can use this line in your form in the view:

```
 <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PATCH">
```

Comment: what url are you trying to post to?

Comment: user/edit/23, 23 is the user id

Comment: what is the form  `action ` ?

Comment: ahh sorry, now i fixed it, thx guys!

Comment: user/profile/{id} but it must be user/edit/{id} for example :D A stupid mistake. But it don't get in the database, the values

Comment: Your form method is for a PATCH but the only route you have is for a POST - you need to add `Route::patch('user/edit/{id}', 'UserController@update');`